# Redis Session Serializer mismatch between 3.2 and 4.2

Tags: spring, session, redis, spring-session

I have a Spring Cloud-based application running on multiple spring-boot servers. All servers share the same Spring Session using @EnableRedisHttpSession.

I now want to integrate a third party widget into my application. Working with the third party, I was able to get initial configuration running, but I'm failing when the third party tries to access the Redis Session data. This is because I am using Spring 4 and the third party uses Spring 3.2. I cannot upgrade the third party's Spring version.

The exception is:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize; nested exception is     
    org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException:     
Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding     serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is     
java.io.InvalidClassException:     org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl; local class     incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 400, local class     serialVersionUID = 320
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: 
org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 400, local class serialVersionUID = 320
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:616) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518) ~[na:1.8.0_66]    
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultDeserializer.deserialize(DefaultDeserializer.java:41) ~[spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:59) ~[spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
... 66 common frames omitted
```

Is there any way to easily translate between the two versions?

Comment: Are you sure, your issue is due to incompatibility of Spring versions? Are you really deserializing exactly the same class you serialized before?

Comment: I would think so, based on the exception description. This is done behind the scenes by @EnableRedisHttpSession code.

Comment: I think you can achieve this by override the RedisSerializer to use a custom strategy that reads and writes your objects for your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

Some days ago i have also faced same issue when i was upgrading spring boot version from 2.2.1 to 2.2.6.

This issue was due to **serialVersionUID** which is present in **SecurityContextImpl** class. It has been changed between spring versions.

In your case it has been changed to 400 to 320 or vice-versa.

**Resolution** :

1. Stop storing session on redis-server via setting property spring.session.store-type=none
2. Use Jackson serialisation to avoid this type of issues in future version upgrades.
3. Override implementation of **SecurityContextImpl** class. No need to do anything only serialVersionUID changes are sufficient.

[image: Issue what i have faced]

Adding a great reference for more details: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/1924