# Cannot deserialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload

Tags: java, spring

I am using `eclipse marse jee`, `spring 4`, `redis 3`.

I downloaded a `spring` example from [here](https://github.com/hmiri/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/double). This example has 4 applications:

`admin` - `gateway` - `resource` - `ui`.

I have ran all of these program. I tested `http://localhost:8080/ui/` and log in with username:admin, password:admin. I got this error in `ui` application.

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.io.InvalidClassException: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 410, local class serialVersionUID = 400
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:41) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeHashValue(AbstractOperations.java:316) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeHashMap(AbstractOperations.java:277) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.entries(DefaultHashOperations.java:227) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.entries(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:101) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:233) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:220) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:141) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:276) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.updateAccessedSessionAttributes(ServletRequestAttributes.java:255) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributes.requestCompleted(AbstractRequestAttributes.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:106) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:125) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:65) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_05]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.io.InvalidClassException: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 410, local class serialVersionUID = 400
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:78) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:36) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:39) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 410, local class serialVersionUID = 400
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:621) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultDeserializer.deserialize(DefaultDeserializer.java:70) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:73) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: looks like a version mismatch. check the dependencies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like SpringSecurityContextImpl can't be deserialized correctly. 410 and 400 means Spring 4.0 and Spring 4.1. There's a similar question for mismatch between Spring 3.2 and Spring 4.2 [Redis Session Serializer mismatch between 3.2 and 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535765/redis-session-serializer-mismatch-between-3-2-and-4-2). That's a bit tricky, because I can see you're just trying to run an example, I think the most straightforward way to fix this is to not store session data in Redis (e.g. remove @EnableRedisHttpSession). Perhaps, also verify that the Spring 4.1 is used everywhere, and Spring 4 is not pulled in by some transitive dependency.

Comment: i found all of applications but it just uses spring 4.1.1

Comment: did you try disabling Redis HttpSession storage? or cleaning it by hand? for dependencies, did you try mvn dependency:tree ?

Answer (score 7):

Looks like your Client and Server has two different class Versions:

```
incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 410, local class serialVersionUID = 400
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:41) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Comment: use same Versions on both sides

Comment: can you expand your answer and tell me how can i change server or client serialVersionUID?

Comment: The serialVersionUID is a Attribute of a serializable class. So you have to use the same Version of the class on both sides

Answer (score 3):

Context : Spring boot app + redis local db (Saving an Employee class object which implements Serializable interface)

Worked perfectly fine but, then I renamed the package name using eclipse refactor and that's when I started getting this issue.

Tried everything by cleaning,building,clearing .m2 repo etc. But nothing helped.

I got little hint by one of the answers here that it is a redis issue and started debugging on redis end.

And found that there was a file named dump.rdb file in which there was a reference with the old package fully qualified name and that's what the problem was.

Just deleted the dump.rdb file from redis and boom, the error was gone.

It took around 2,3 hours and I hope it might help someone and save some time.

Comment: Thank you very much, This was the exact answer for my issue.

Answer (score 2):

For me, all i did to resolve this error was to delete all redis key using the Redis client `redis-cli FLUSHALL`

Comment: `flushall` seemed to work for me as well

Answer (score 0):

Objects stored in session were serialized by previous version of the app. When new application was deployed some classes changed signatures and now deserializer is unable to unwrap due to conflicted versions.

The best way is to tell deserializer to igonre this value by providing `springSessionDefaultRedisSerializer` which will output null value:

```java
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig implements BeanClassLoaderAware {
    
    private ClassLoader classLoader;

    @Bean("springSessionDefaultRedisSerializer")
    public RedisSerializer<Object> getRedisSerializer() {
        return new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer(classLoader) {
            @Override
            public Object deserialize(@Nullable byte[] bytes) {
                try {
                    return super.deserialize(bytes);
                } catch (SerializationException ex) {
                    log.warn(ex.getMessage());
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
    
    @Override
    public void setBeanClassLoader(@NotNull ClassLoader classLoader) {
        this.classLoader = classLoader;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearing redis cache hekped in my case:

```bash
docker exec -it redis redis-cli -a redis-password FLUSHALL
```